# Need help explanation of these lines of code

Tags: php

I am learning php OOP from lynda tutorial and i came upon these 3 lines of codes. I know these are general php codes but i did not understand them. So I need please some explanation of each line what it does. Does it redefine the root of the php script it is written in and how does it do it exactly ?

thanks a lot in advance for your help i would really appreciate it

```
$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/root_testing') + 7;
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find position of `'/root_testing'` in `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, then add `7` - start from where `_` is

```
$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/root_testing') + 7;
```

Cut that end part of script name. `/root_testing` becomes `testing`

```
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
```

Define new constant `WWW_ROOT` as `testing`

```
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
```

Comment: thank you Justinas, so define what does it exactly define here ? what is www_root?

Comment: @jwright91 It's just string `testing`, where and how it's used you should check further code. Usually it's where HTTP requests entry point `index.php` is located